# Trying to understand the power requirements for home electrical backup

Tags: electrical

I'm considering partial electrical backup incase of power failure.

Considering a solar solution.

My power company tells me my usage per month is 60.0 kWh

So I assume me daily usage is on average about 60/30 = 2 kWh. Does that make sense?

So I need a battery that can store 2+ kW and a charging source that supply the same daily.

Gotta a feeling I'm way off.

Given I use 60 kWh per month - what kind of capacity do I need?

Thanks.

*** CORRECTION ***

I misread the bill.

My average DAILY usage ranges from 10-50 kWh - i guess the major factor is AC. During the winter months it's 10 kWh avg daily.

Regardless, let's say I plan for 20 kWh max daily (not using AC) - so what kind of setup do I need.

Also, I'm doing an emergency backup only (furnace + fridge + some lights) - so let's say I need 10 kWh daily. I will find the actual numbers using a watt meter - but let's use that as a starting point.

Apologies for the misread - but the above number seems to be a fair starting point.

Comment: That is very low usage unless you have mostly gas for water heater, cooking and heat and no air conditioning.

Comment: I checked the bill - that's mainly AC during the summer. For colder months - it's much lower and I made sure I was looking at electrical section. Yes - cooking, heating and water heater is gas. But given the above sample, I'd like some direction. Most probably the battery will be Li PH4 12V. In fact, since this is a partial backup during power failure, I'd think daily consumption would be less than 1 kWh. I'm assuming my math above and understanding above is correct.

Comment: Don't plan for a pack that matches your consumption. Aim for a pack that runs forty percent greater or higher. One should not charge to one hundred percent, nor discharge beyond twenty percent remaining.

Comment: How many days of power out? Do you need to run everything in a multi-day outage? Do you have time-if-day electricity metering and want to shift to off peak charging from the grid?

Comment: You need to consider peak instantaneous draw in addition to daily average. It's probably not a nice constant 83W draw 24/7 but rather short peaks of at least hundreds of watts, possibly even a thousand or a couple thousand. 2kWh of usable battery capacity could power your house for an average day, but the inverter in front of it will need an instantaneous watt rating high enough to run the peak critical loads that you want to run at the same time.

Comment: It's also possible that, if you go away to work on weekdays and are at home on weekends, your daily power varies significantly from that monthly average.

Comment: This can get very much out in the weeds. You might be prone to conserve more actively when on backup. To the extent there's daylight some will be made and used that won't need to be stored. But charging in poor conditions (gray, overcast, rainy) is a tiny fraction of full sun, so you may need to carry multiple days, or vastly oversize the array so that the tiny fraction is adequate to charge anyway. So what seems a "simple question" becomes a vast array of tradeoffs very quickly. As one datapoint, my pretty efficient fridge (a good thing to backup) uses a bit less than 1 kWh/day

Comment: Maybe I'm behind the times, but solar systems don't typically charge batteries from grid or backup generator feeding house. So the question is are you contemplating a solar system with inverter output capable of starting the A/C? if not then the calculation is generator sized to operate A/C plus battery charger current.

Comment: All else aside, you don't want 12v batteries for a whole-house system; that's far to low of voltage. 36v or 48v would save you a lot of the trouble and costs of thick wiring and high-amperage components. The cost should be comparable on the batteries either way, they are basically sold by WH capacity, not voltage, though 12v is more common and thus slightly cheaper in smaller amounts. You need to do an energy census and tally up all the appliances you want to use in a blackout, then multiply those watts by tyhe # of hours of backup to arrive at a total WH figure.

Answer (score 3):

> Gotta a feeling I'm way off.

You're way off.  It might be a problem with units - kW and kWH are quite different things and people confuse them constantly, at least until they get energy basics under their belt.  Batteries are sized in kWH.

The [EPA reports](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/use-of-energy/electricity-use-in-homes.php#:%7E:text=The%20average%20U.S.%20household%20consumes,kilowatthours%20(kWh)%20per%20year.&text=However%2C%20electricity%20use%20in%20homes,States%20and%20across%20housing%20types.) that the average house uses 30 kWH per day or 1.2 kWH per hour.  This is 5 amps at 240V.

I can tell you from personal measurement that a basic refrigerator takes 1 kWH per day (averaging 42 watts - really - you can't go by how much heat comes off it, because it didn't make that heat, just [moved it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto&list=PLv0jwu7G_DFVIot1ubOZdR-KC-LFdOVqi).)  People tell me their fancy deluxe fridges with vertical full-height fridge and freezer section and ice in the door take 2-3 kWH per day.

> My power company tells me my usage per month is 60.0 kWh. So I assume me daily usage is on average about 60/30 = 2 kWh. Does that make sense?

No chance of that. Something has gone haywire with your data collection.

Comment: Agreed, 60kWh per month is implausibly low usage for just a fridge and air conditioning, never mind everything else that’s normally in a house or apartment.

Answer (score 1):

#### Battery capacity

You need the maximum daily figures, not average daily figures. Assuming that you have a smart meter, your power company should be able to provide you with those figures.

If they cant then either double it to 4. Or buy/rent  a measuring device.

#### Invertor size

This needs to handle instaneous loads. Many gadgets have a higher draw at startup, such as ACs, motors, fridges.

Either check these on the labels of your gadgets, or double the  daily usage to 4 for your invertor.

The last thing you want is for the invertor to shut down or the voltage to drop. Voltage drop will dim the lights and sustained voltage drop may actually harm some appliances.

Depending on the design, its frequency may drop, which would be worse.

#### Summary

Select a system where you can add another battery, that way you can try it with a figure of 2 per day before buying the 2nd battery

Answer (score -1):

Home Appliance  Energy Used
Air conditioner 900 to 4,100 watts an hour
Heater -Gas
Lighting    0.61 kilowatt-hours per month
Television  58.6 kilowatt-hours
Desktop computer    60 to 250 watts
Laptop  15 to 60 watts
DVR 8 to 15 watts
Video game console  90 watts
Refrigerator    300 to 800 watts
Freezer 30 to 100 watts
Oven- Gas
Microwave   0.12 kilowatt-hours per five minutes
Coffeemaker 0.4 to 0.26 kilowatt-hours
Dishwasher  0.5 kilowatt-hours per load
Ceiling fan 0.9 kilowatt hours per day

That ads to way over 2kWh per day, unless you do not run the fridge, or Dishwasher or washing machine, and forget about HVAC